# Why does using declaration not expose pointer to member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Consider:

```
struct foo
{
    void foobar(){}
};

struct bar : protected foo
{
    using foo::foobar;
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
    b.foobar(); // Fine
    &bar::foobar; // Not fine
}
```

I'm wondering what the rationale for letting using declarations expose the member, but not a pointer to it. In fact it would seem all using declarations that changes access level works for everything except taking the address of an exposed function.

**UPDATE**: An example which resembles my real use case better:

```
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

struct foo
{
    void foobar() {}
};

struct bar : protected foo
{
    using foo::foobar;
    bar() { boost::bind( &bar::foobar, this )(); } // Crashes VS2008, GCC 4.1.1 fails to compile as it tries to go through foo*
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
}
```

However, Mike Seymours' explanation is spot on and explains why GCC fails. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? http://ideone.com/HbRik

Comment: @PaulManta - Might just be VS2008 then, going to do some further investigation.

Comment: Maybe you can mention which compiler you are using in the body of the question? Besides being informative, it will allow me to remove my downvote.

Comment: To those that are voting to close: **RETHINK** you might not have understood the question.

Comment: Will do, I'm getting some really strange behavior across compilers, especially when I involve `boost::bind`, which makes the VS2008 optimizing compiler straight up crash while GCC fails to compile. I'll update in a bit with a better example.

Comment: VS 2010 also refuses to compile above snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[I am assuming that in your program the code is: `void (bar::*p)() = &bar::foobar;`]*

The problem is not that the *using declaration* does not bring the identifier into space, but the semantics of `&bar::foobar`. I am considering (I would have done it if I had the time) refilling a Defect Report with this. There is already one such report.

Basically the problem is that the using declaration brings the base function into scope for lookup in the derived type, and the access specifiers for the expression `&bar::foobar` will be checked against `bar`. **But**, the result of the expression `&bar::foobar` is of type `void (foo::*)()`, not `void (bar::*)()`. Now, after evaluation of `&bar::foobar` if you try to use that as a `void (bar::*)()` the compiler will try to perform the conversion of the pointer to member but will fail because `foo` is a `protected` base of `bar`, and in the context of `main` you don't have access to that relationship.

Note that I consider that to be a defect in the language for two reasons: first it breaks your code: `void (bar::*p)() = &bar::foobar;` surprisingly fails to compile. Secondly, it breaks access protections in other cases:

```
class base {
protected: void f() {}
};
struct derived : base {
   void foo( base& b ) {
       b.f();                // Error
       b.*(&derived::f)();   // OK
   }
};
```

This problem is actually symmetric to yours, while in yours the surprising type of the address-of-member operation inhibits your use case when it shouldn't, in this case it allows an usage that is against the intent of `protected`.

Related links:

- [DR 203 - Type of address-of-member expression](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#203)
- [DR 1007 - Protected access and pointers to members](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1007)

---

After the comment on using `bind`, it might not be the case that you are trying to convert the pointer to member to a pointer to member of `bar` directly, but somewhere inside `bind` code will be generated to apply the pointer to member to an instance of `bar`, and that requires the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this answers the original question; David Rodriguez has answered the update.

Your code is fine. According to the language standard:

> 7.3.3/2 Every *using-declaration* is a *declaration* and a *member-declaration*

That means you are declaring `foobar` to be a member of `bar` as well as `foo`, and so referring to it as `bar::foobar` is just as legitimate as `foo::foobar`.

My compiler (GCC) agrees with this; if yours doesn't, then it would appear to have a bug.

Comment: I think he mistakenly removed a bit from the question. `void (bar::*p)() = &bar::foobar;` will not compile.

Comment: nitpick: a using-declaration that is a member-declaration within a class x does not declare a member of class x.